# Updating the current datagridview instead of adding another in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello sorry for asking too many questions im just really a beginner on VB.net but what I wanted to do know is instead of adding another rows how can I update that instead? like Row = Bulgogi,1,45 and then when I click on the picturebox again it will be Row = Bulgogi,2,90 and not adding Bulgogi, 1 ,45 and Bulgogi, 2 ,90 also the Quantity isnt working just stuck in 1 everytime it clicks but the increment is working fine :/

```
Private BibimbapQuantity = 0
Private BulgogiQuantity = 0
Private BibimbapPrice As Integer
Private BulgogiPrice As Integer
Private TotalPriceInt As Integer
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonBibimbap.Click
    BibimbapQuantity += 1
    BibimbapPrice = 45 * BibimbapQuantity
    Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Bibimbap", BibimbapQuantity, BibimbapPrice)
    totalPrice.Text = BibimbapPrice + BulgogiPrice
End Sub

Private Sub buttonBulgogi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonBulgogi.Click
    BulgogiQuantity += 1
    BulgogiPrice = 50 * BulgogiQuantity
    Dim Satisfy As Integer = 0
    Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Bulgogi", BulgogiQuantity, BibimbapPrice)
    totalPrice.Text = BibimbapPrice + BulgogiPrice
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this before the Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add

```
Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
```

Comment: TBH the quantity doesn't stick in 1 but if you mean the BulgogiPrice was stuck, you should change the BibimbapPrice to BulgogiPrice in the buttonBulgogi_Click

Comment: But now they are both replacing in the same Rows ._.

Comment: Try to add both Bibimbap and Bulgogi in each click

Comment: what? ._. sorry :<

Comment: Replace Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Bibimbap", BibimbapQuantity, BibimbapPrice) and Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Bulgogi", BulgogiQuantity, BibimbapPrice) to Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Bibimbap", BibimbapQuantity, BibimbapPrice)
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Bulgogi", BulgogiQuantity, BulgogiPrice)

Comment: But I want to separate them :< not double add them in a single click :<

Comment: This doesn't change the result but just display both of the results at the same time. Pls take a look and describe the result that you prefer if you don't satisfy with that

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in the `AddItemToCart()` method for explanations.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim bibimbapQuantity, bulgogiQuantity, kimchiQuantity As Integer
    Dim bibimbapTotalPrice, bulgogiTotalPrice, kimchiTotalPrice As Integer
    Const bibimbapPrice As Integer = 45, bulgogiPrice As Integer = 50, kimchiPrice As Integer = 35

    Private Sub buttonBibimbap_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonBibimbap.Click
        bibimbapQuantity += 1
        bibimbapTotalPrice = bibimbapPrice * bibimbapQuantity
        AddItemToCart("Bibimbap", bibimbapQuantity, bibimbapTotalPrice)
    End Sub

    Private Sub buttonBulgogi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonBulgogi.Click
        bulgogiQuantity += 1
        bulgogiTotalPrice = bulgogiPrice * bulgogiQuantity
        AddItemToCart("Bulgogi", bulgogiQuantity, bulgogiTotalPrice)
    End Sub

    Private Sub buttonKimchi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonKimchi.Click
        kimchiQuantity += 1
        kimchiTotalPrice = kimchiPrice * kimchiQuantity
        AddItemToCart("Kimchi", kimchiQuantity, kimchiTotalPrice)
    End Sub

    Sub AddItemToCart(foodName As String, quantity As Integer, totalPrice As Integer)
        Dim foundFood As Boolean = False ' initially the food name is not found yet
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 ' loop each row in grid
            If DataGridView1(0, i).Value = foodName Then ' if current row is the food you're adding
                foundFood = True ' food is found
                DataGridView1(1, i).Value = quantity ' set new quantity
                DataGridView1(2, i).Value = totalPrice ' set new total price
                Exit For ' don't check the rest of the rows because it has been found
            End If
        Next
        If Not foundFood Then ' if food is not found in the grid
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(foodName, quantity, totalPrice) ' add a new line in the grid
        End If
        textboxTotalPrice.Text = bibimbapTotalPrice + bulgogiTotalPrice + kimchiTotalPrice ' calculate total for all foods
    End Sub

End Class
```